# Улучшить алгоритм раскрытия списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, оптимизация

У меня есть такая структура данных [[1,2,3],...,[5,6,7]]. Необходимо каждый список раскрыть в следующем виде:

```
[
[1, [2, 3]],
[2, [1, 3]],
[3, [1, 2]],
]
```

Таким образом, при поступлении на вход `[[1,2,3],[8,9],[5,6,7]]`, будет получено:

```
[
    [1, [2, 3]],
    [2, [1, 3]],
    [3, [1, 2]],
    [8, [9]],
    [9, [8]],
    [5, [6, 7]],
    [6, [5, 7]],
    [7, [5, 6]],
]
```

]
Сейчас я написал следующую функцию:

```
def disclose_list(dlist):
    tmp = []
    new = []
    for i in tqdm.tqdm(dlist):
        for j in i:
            tmp = i.copy()
            tmp.remove(j)
            new.append([j, tmp])
    return new
```

Она работает, но медленно и ест ОЧЕНЬ много памяти. Для оценки масштабов проблемы - передаю я в нее 4754243 таких списка и это далеко не предел. Можно ли как-то улучшить эту функцию? В первую очередь по использованию памяти, потому что ест она ну очень много.

Comment: Укажите, что у вас на входе, так же, как и нужный выход сейчас указан

Comment: Не совсем понял вопроса, входные данные я указал в самом начале вопроса, если вы об этом.

Comment: После исправления уже лучше, но всё равно непонятно, что на месте `...`. Короче каких длин могут быть подсписки?

Comment: Подсписки могут быть любой длины.

Comment: можете указать полностью входной список, для которого в результате должен получиться `[[1, [2, 3]],[2, [1, 3]],[3, [1, 2]]]` ?

Comment: Вот, теперь нормальный пример

Comment: Попробуйте `numpy.roll()` использовать

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, как оно мне может помочь, да и хотелось бы обойтись без numpy и других подключаемых библиотек, учитывая, что потом я все равно буду это переводить в словарь.

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, что у вас получится оптимизировать код без внешних модулей.
я бы посоветовал сделать что-то типа этого:

```
import itertools

a = [1,2,3]
mut = itertools.permutations(a)
res = set((x[0],tuple(sorted(x[1:]))) for x in list(mut))
print(res)
# {(3, (1, 2)), (2, (1, 3)), (1, (2, 3))}
```

я, кстати, не уверен в сильном улучшении эффективности, поскольку пермутация для больших списков - довольно емкое занятие.

Comment: Если используется одна функция из пакета, зачем импортировать весь пакет? )

Comment: @CrazyElf та не https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/187403

Comment: @CrazyElf да я как-то приучил себя к полному импорту, чтобы потом в функциях не путаться.